# How do you tell you are running in debug mode in sdk2?

Tags: rally, appsdk2

How do I tell programatically in SDK2 if I am running in debug (local) mode (not installed in Rally)?

I was looking for something in Rally.app.Context but didn't see anything obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the context for that purpose, as far as I know, but here is a trick that can tell you if it is running in Rally, or outside:

```
 if (window.parent.Rally.alm) {
     console.log('inside');
  }
  else{
     console.log('outside');
  }
```